# Can the GAC be shared between multiple machines?

Tags: .net, gac

As per my knowledge shared assembly can be accessed for multiple application from same machine. Is it possible to access GAC from different machine ?

Comment: Your title asks about sharing GACs, your question simply states "access the GAC from a different machine" - in the end the GAC is just a folder so yes, you could access it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The GAC is a per machine cache.

[GAC on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)

Answer (score 1):

I would say clearly not, Global Assembly Cache is global for all application in the same machine, each machine needs to have the assembly locally available if your application is loading them from the GAC.